# Reading a javascript variable's value

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to read the value of a javascript variable using Xpath
the js text is as follows:

```
 var item_url = 'nahodka_sobaki_prodam_schenkov_labradora_278393584'
  , item_phone = '994h4ada5cc0f9605334b81edd8a4ad548189hbfea9627bf5beb5cb7c699efh1daha84bda6a8ddec8bd33706bf0bc5h849098' ;
```

I only want item_phone value 
I tried :

```
$x('//script[contains(.,"item_phone")]/text()')[0]
```

it returns

```
 var item_url = 'nahodka_sobaki_prodam_schenkov_labradora_278393584'
  , item_phone = '994h4ada5cc0f9605334b81edd8a4ad548189hbfea9627bf5beb5cb7c699efh1daha84bda6a8ddec8bd33706bf0bc5h849098' ;
```

I split it by ',' but it return same text, what is my problem ?

Answer (score 4):

your code

```
$x('//script[contains(.,"item_phone")]/text()')[0]
```

returns the whole string. Try the xpath

```
substring-before(substring-after(//script[contains(.,'item_phone')]/text(), "item_phone = '"), "' ;")
```

Comment: How should I use this on chrome console ?