# Getting value from inside div using XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have the following div

```
<div data-dmid="product-detail-page" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="3600542198158">
```

from which I would like to extract the itemid -> 3600542198158

I was using the following Xpath which does however not return any value:

```
//div[@data-dmid='product-detail-page']/@itemid
```

Could please someone advise how to built the Xpath correctly for it

---

## #

Unfortunately I have to renew my question.

I was looking for the code with Firefox inspection tool.
Looking at the html source code which is different to the output with the inspection tool I have the following part which will be interesting:

```
<div class="onCanvas content-with-footer">

    <div id="container-main" class="content-main">
        <div data-dmid="uvp-banner-container" style="height: 54px; width: 100%"></div>
            <script>
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                    var props = {};
                    ReactInit.initReactComponent("contentViewService", "UvpBannerContainer", props, document.querySelector("[data-dmid='uvp-banner-container']"));
                });
           </script>
        <div id="react-product-detail-page"></div>
<script>
var props = {
    gtin: 3600542198158,
    locale: dmSettings.localeLanguage
};
ReactInit.initReactComponent("product-detail-page", "ProductDetailPage", props, document.getElementById("react-product-detail-page"));
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var props = {
                locale: dmSettings.localeLanguage
            };

        ReactInit.initReactComponent("product-detail-page", "PriceLegend", props, document.getElementById("react-price-legend"));
    });
</script>
```

I would need to get the gtin (plain number) of the second script.

I would like to use the xpath in a scraping tool why only plain xpath code will work for me.

Thank you again and please excuse my previous not fully correct question.

Comment: How are you evaluating the expression? It's generally correct.. as shown in this xpather example: http://xpather.com/3pAh8e5b

Comment: The following xpath will give me the whole scrip text -> "//div[@class='onCanvas content-with-footer']//script[2]" Now I only would need to extract the gtin value

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you don't mind JavaScript and jQuery since you didn't specify:

```js
var itemId = $("div[data-dmid]").attr("itemid");
console.log(itemId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-dmid="product-detail-page" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="3600542198158">
```

Comment: Let me know if this fit your needs. Also, if it doesn't then please reword your question and add extra information.

Comment: Thank you acarlstein for your answer. I had to update my question due to new info I gained.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with help of another post on Stackoverflow.

[Reading a javascript variable's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778534/reading-a-javascript-variables-value)

The correct code for my updated question is

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='onCanvas content-with-footer']//script[2][contains(.,'gtin')]/text(), "gtin: "), ",")
```

Thank you for any help.